# OBIEE password protect analysis send via e-amil using an agent

Tags: agent, obiee

I want to e-mail an OBIEE analysis using an agent. It will be mailed as an excel attachment. The e-mail is not the problem, but how can I configure the file to be password protected?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it out of the box. You will have to write a Java application that could set the password. Have a look at the following blog post - http://www.rittmanmead.com/2010/09/oracle-bi-ee-11g-action-framework-java-ejbs-and-pdf-watermarks/

Though the blog post above does not give you the solution but at least gives an idea what you will have to do.

Regards.